# Questions about If X is reflexive, X is weakly sequentially complete in Conway's book.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

[image]

[image]

I don't understand this proof. Which PUB is using here and why the $\lim\langle x_n,x^*\rangle$ exists from $x_n$ clusters to $x$?

Thank you!

Comment: What is PUB?  That is not a widely understood acronym.

Comment: @ncmathsadist probably Principle of Uniform Boundedness [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of weakly Cauchy, we know that for each $x^*$ in $\mathscr{X}^*$ the sequence $(\langle x^*,x_n \rangle)_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{F}$. Hence $(\langle x_n,x^* \rangle)_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{F}$ for each $x^*\in\mathscr{X}^*$, where the $x_n$ here is viewed as the image of the element $x_n$ under the canonical isometry from $\mathscr{X}$ into $\mathscr{X}^{**}$. Since Cauchy sequences are bounded, we have
$$
\sup_n |\langle x_n,x^* \rangle| < \infty
$$
for every $x^*\in\mathscr{X}^*$. As the space $\mathscr{X}^*$ is complete, we can apply the uniform boundedness principle to obtain that $\sup_n\|x_n\|<\infty$.
Taking $M:=\sup_n\|x_n\|$, we have the $M$ used in Conway's proof.
Then the argument proceeds, as Conway writes, by using the fact that the unit ball of a reflexive space is weakly compact.

The limit $\lim_n \langle x_n,x^* \rangle$ exists because we know $(\langle x_n,x^*\rangle)_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ is complete.

Comment: We know the limit exists but how can we get $x_n\rightarrow x$ weakly? Thank you!

Comment: From compactness we know that $x$ is a weak cluster point of $(x_n)_n$. Hence $\langle x,x^* \rangle$ is a cluster point of $(\langle x_n,x^*\rangle)_n$ for each $x^*\in\mathscr{X}^*$. It follows from the fact that $\lim_n\langle x_n,x^*\rangle$ exists that $\langle x_n,x^*\rangle \to \langle x,x^*\rangle$, for every $x^*\in\mathscr{X}^*$. Therefore $x_n\to x$ weakly.

Comment: Get it! Thank you so much!! Can I ask you another question? For a normed space X, we have ball X=ball $X^{**}$. How to imply $X=X^{**}$? Thank you!

Comment: @AnswerLee The unit balls of $X$ and $X^{**}$ are equal only when $X$ is reflexive. In this case, we must have $X=X^{**}$.

Comment: @AnswerLee It's a general fact in a uniform space that a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ with a cluster point $x$ (so that for every neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ the set $\{n: x_n \in O\}$ is infinite) converges to $x$. The compactness gives you this cluster point.

Comment: @John Griffin But how ball $X$=ball $X^{**}$ to get $X$ is reflexive?

Comment: @AnswerLee Suppose the unit ball of $X$ is included in the unit ball of $Y$. Then, if $x\in X$, $x\ne0$, we have that $x/\|x\|$ is in the unit ball of $X$ and hence the unit ball of $Y$. Therefore $x=\|x\| (x/\|x\|)$ is in $Y$. This proves that if the unit ball of $X$ is equal to the unit ball of $Y$, then $X=Y$.

Comment: @John Griffin What if $||x||$ goes to infinity and is $||x||(x/||x||)$ still in Y?

Comment: @AnswerLee The $x$ in my previous comment is fixed so I don't know what you mean by "$\|x\|$ goes to infinity".

Comment: @John Griffin Is that possible $||x||=\infty$? Thank you!

Comment: @AnswerLee No. A norm doesn't take infinite values. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: @John Griffin Get it! Thank you so much!